# Execute .Add() method on ICollection<>

Tags: c#, .net

I have an object of *Some Type* that I know implements `ICollection<T>`. I do NOT know (at compile time) what the Type of the generic collection is- It could be virtually anything.

I have a new object of Type T, but I still (at compile time) do not know what that Type is.

I want to do something like this:

```
object myCollection; // I know it implements ICollection<T>, but nothing more
object newObject; // I know that newObject.GetType() matches T, but nothing more

myCollection.Add( newObject ); // This syntax is clearly ludicrous, but...
```

how do I make that last line work (the .Add) without using reflection? Right now, I'm reflecting the MethodInfo for the Type constructed from

```
object myCollection;
object newObject;

var typ = newObject.GetType();
var colTyp = typeof( ICollection<> ).MakeGenericType( new Type[] { typ } );
var mi = colTyp.GetMethodInfo( "Add" );
mi.Invoke( myCollection, new object[] { newObject } );
```

This seems like a performance nightmare, even if I did some caching based on `newObject.GetType()`.

Is there a better way?

EDIT: Not using dynamic objects

Comment: Can you make your collection implement non-generic `ICollection`?

Comment: How do you retrieve that collection? Maybe there's a nicer way to have it return what you want rather than having the consumer try fancy tricks to do it.

Comment: C# is statically typed. What do you expect? If you have a compile-time type (declared type) of `object`, your choices are reflection or `dynamic`, the two techniques you mention already.

Comment: A reference to the collection is retrieved using Reflection. All collection members in a Type are returned. I want to be able to add to the "right" collection based on the `object.GetType()` passed in to an object-level (the object containing the collections) method. Also, the `ICollection<>` is necessary because the class needs to mimic a different class which uses `ICollection<>`

Comment: I don't suppose you could retrieve a reference to the collection via a statically typed generic method or something?

Comment: While I suspect Jeppe Stig Nielsen 's question "What do you expect" was rhetorical, here is what I would expect of a language that is as dynamically changing over time as C#: `((ICollection<>) myCollection).Add( newObject )`, where the compiler would inject optimized code before the method invocation that verifies that the Type of newObject matches the Type of the generic parameter to ICollection<> and throws an exception if the Types don't align. I suspect that the compiler would be able to optimize this far better than the Reflection-based solution I have now.

Comment: Why do you think that the code in your question is a "performance nightmare"?